# Wordpress Permalinks Woes w/ Custom Post Type - constantly needs to be resaved to function

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, custom-post-type

I'm using the Fluxus theme and I've made a sort of link directory (for offsite linking to galleries) using the 'grid' based archive structure and custom post types.

It's located at http://alexandermasters.com/access and, when it works, it's fantastic. The problem is, it stops working periodically (without having logged in or updated or anything), and then I end up with the catch all 'page not found' ..page. However, without making any adjustments, resaving the permalink structure (ie settings > permalinks > save changes) makes it function again.

Not sure where the problem lies, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This usually happens when a plugin invokes [flush_rewrite_rules()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules), but the fact that it's happening on its own periodically is confusing. Are you using a plugin for custom post types?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. I've got Contact Form 7, Google Calendar Events, and Really Simple CAPTCHA.

Comment: So the /access page is saved as a page with the grid layout? If you don't have any other plugins then it's probably the theme's functions.php file causing the flush. I think it'll be best to contact the developer for support, since this seems like a theme-based issue.